# « Finir de travailler » ou « quitter le travail » ?

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot

J'aimerais savoir ce qui est mieux:

dire,

> Quand je finis de travailler je rentre à la maison

ou

> Quand je quitte le travail je rentre à la maison

?

Y a-t-il une différence ?

Answer (score 5):

Ces deux phrases sont correctes :

> (1) Quand je finis de travailler, je rentre à la maison.
>   (2) Quand je quitte le travail, je rentre à la maison.

Elles n'ont pas exactement le même sens.

Dans la phrase (2), « le travail » désigne le lieu de travail. Lorsque je quitte mon lieu de travail, je rentre à la maison ; la phrase indique que je ne vais pas faire des courses, ou à la piscine, etc.

Une manière plus courante d'exprimer (2) serait

> (2') En sortant du travail, je rentre à la maison.

Dans la phrase (1), « travailler » désigne l'activité. La phrase (1) peut être utilisée même par quelqu'un qui n'a pas de lieu de travail fixe (par exemple un vendeur à domicile, un chauffeur de taxi, etc.).

Le verbe *finir* implique qu'une tâche est terminée. Si mon travail est défini par des horaires (par exemple : je travaille de 9h à 17h), « finir de travailler » signifie qu'il est l'heure de quitter le travail. Mais si mon travail est défini par des tâches à accomplir, « finis de travailler » signifie que j'ai fini mes tâches. Pour dire que j'ai choisi d'arrêter de travailler (par exemple parce qu'il est l'heure de partir), on dirait

> (3) Quand j'arrête de travailler, je rentre à la maison.

Les trois phrases utilisent le présent. Elles désignent des actions habituelles : tous les jours, quand je … Dans la langue courante (pas dans la langue soutenue), on peut aussi utiliser le présent comme futur proche : ce soir, quand je …, mais c'est plus rare.

Comment: Merci beaucoup, c'est plus clair maintenant!

Comment: As a teacher, I can attest that there is a clear difference between *“quitter le travail”* and *“finir de travailler”*

Answer (score 2):

Ni l'un, ni l'autre. On peut dire par exemple :

> Quand j'ai fini de travailler, je rentre à la maison
>
> Quand je quitte le travail, je rentre à la maison

Je dirais plutôt:

> Après mon travail, je rentre chez moi.

Note:

La phrase « Quand je finis de travailler, je rentre à la maison » est grammaticalement correcte mais implique une simultanéité entre les deux actions.

« Quand je finis de travailler » signifie plus « Quand je suis en train de terminer mon travail » que « Quand mon travail est terminé ».

A moins qu'il y ait réellement un recouvrement entre les deux, il me semble donc plus logique de considérer la deuxième action comme succédant à la première (d'abord je finis de travailler et ensuite je rentre chez moi), d'où ma suggestion d'utiliser le passé composé « Quand j'ai fini de travailler, je rentre... »

Comment: Merci beaucoup! Donc quand faut-il utiliser "quitter le travail"?  / Et, "finir de travailler", ça existe?

Comment: Premiers exemples trouvés sur http://www.linguee.fr/ : « Les personnes couramment exposées à cette matière active doivent prendre une douche chaque jour avant de quitter le travail. » et « Quand le séisme s'est produit, je venais juste de finir de travailler dans le potager et je me préparais à regarder la télé. »

Comment: Merci beaucoup! j'ai une mauvaise connexion internet. Je voulais demander qu'elle était alors la différence  entre ces deux phrases, mais maintenant que ma connexion s'est retablie j'ai vu la réponse Gilles

Answer (score 0):

Quitter le travail is to permanently leave, without returning.

Finir le travail is to end the job, with expectation of resuming in the future.

Replace work with  "Life"

Quit versus end

Quitter la vie is to die.